# How to find all occurences of an element inside an array of objects and sum their corresponding values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects as below :

```
[
  { code: "a", value: 20 },
  { code: "b", value: 20 },
  { code: "c", value: 20 },
  { code: "a", value: 20 },
  { code: "b", value: 20 },
]
```

I want to reduce it by adding values for all unique codes

```
[
  { code: "a", value: 40 },
  { code: "b", value: 40 },
  { code: "c", value: 20 },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? We're willing to help you with your code but right now it seems like you expect us to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` for grouping the objects by `code` and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

```js
let arr = [{code : 'a', value :20},{code : 'b', value :20},{code : 'c', value :20},{code : 'a',value :20},{code : 'b', value :20}],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {code, value}) => {
      (a[code] || (a[code] = {code, value: 0})).value += value;
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` to store the code-value lookup object, and iterate through that object with `Object.entries()` then manipulate to get the final value

```js
const arr = [
  { code: "a", value: 20 },
  { code: "b", value: 20 },
  { code: "c", value: 20 },
  { code: "a", value: 20 },
  { code: "b", value: 20 },
]

const codeValueMapping = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (acc[el.code]) {
    acc[el.code] += el.value
  } else {
    acc[el.code] = el.value
  }
  return acc
}, {})

const res = Object.entries(codeValueMapping).map(([code, value]) => ({
  code,
  value,
}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution would be by using set in ECMA 6

```
[...new Set(YOUR_ARRAY.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse)
```

Comment: `stringify` (each element) + `map` + `Set` + `map` (again) + `parse` (each element).  This is overkilled and provides a poor performance approach.